# How can capture Click event if element is iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have appended a iframe with youtube embed url in a div which id is div1. I want  to do something when click happened on iframe.

i am using this jquery code but it is not working.

```
$('#div1 iframe').bind('click', function(){
         alert('clicked on iframe');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you have id for iframe or not. but you can try to catch the click even of the document in the iframe:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  alert("iframe clicked");
}
```

Though this doesn't solve your cross site problem, FYI [jQuery has been updated to play well with iFrames](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/05/14/jquery-edge-better-support-for-other-windows-and-documents):

```
$('#iframe_id').bind('click', function(event) { });
```

Comment: Can i use document.getElementsByTagName('iframe') instead of document.getElementById("iframe_id") ?

Comment: Ya you can do that.just remember that it'll get all the iframes from your page.

Comment: If you have id for your iframe,then you can use jquery to make your task easy.

Comment: This code is not working. document.getElementsByTagName("iframe") is selecting element but document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").contentWindow is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
function iframeclick() {
    document.getElementById("theiframe").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("theiframe").contentWindow.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This we can use achive with jquery and its is also possible with javascript

```
$('.inner iframe').bind('click', function(){
             alert('clicked on iframe');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is vanilla JS - and resolved a similar issue for me where I needed to close some dropdowns on the parent if the iFrame was clicked

```
  public static iFrameClickHandler = {
        iFrame: undefined,
        mouseOverIframe: false,
        mouseOver: function() {
            this.mouseOverIframe = true;
        },
        mouseLeave: function() {
            this.mouseOverIframe = false;
            window.focus();
        },
        windowBlur: function() {
            if (this.mouseOverIframe) this.fireClickEvent();
        },
        fireClickEvent: function() {
            // do what you wanna do here
        },
        init: function() {
            this.mouseOver = this.mouseOver.bind(this);
            this.mouseLeave = this.mouseLeave.bind(this);
            this.windowBlur = this.windowBlur.bind(this);
            this.iFrame = document.querySelector('class/id of your iframe wrapper');
            this.iFrame.addEventListener('mouseover', this.mouseOver);
            this.iFrame.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseLeave);
            window.addEventListener('blur', this.windowBlur);
            window.focus();
        },
        destroy: function() {
            this.iFrame.removeEventListener('mouseover', this.mouseOver);
            this.iFrame.removeEventListener('mouseleave', this.mouseLeave);
            window.removeEventListener('blur', this.windowBlur);
        }
    }
```